# How to kill one process and it's all child process Linux?

Tags: linux, shell

```
user1    27913 41004  4 15:54 pts/202  00:00:02 python demo.py
user1    31916 27913  0 15:55 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
user1    31917 27913  0 15:55 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
user1    31918 27913  0 15:55 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
user1    31919 27913  0 15:55 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
user1    31920 27913  0 15:55 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
user1    31921 27913  0 15:55 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
user1    31922 27913  0 15:55 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
user1    31923 27913  0 15:55 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
```

There's a process `27913`, I want to kill it and all it's child process, how can I make it work?

> update python script:

below's my `demo.py`

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import time

def foo(num):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(num)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as exe:
            exe.map(foo, range(1,4))
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124127/kill-all-descendant-processes

Comment: use `pkill -p PPID` where PPID is the parent process ID

Comment: @norok2 it seems not working `pkill  -P 27913  `

Comment: `pkill -9 -P 27913` ?

Comment: @norok2Thanks for your replying, `pkill -9 -P 27913` still not working.But `kill -- -27913` happened to  work. Can you help me figuring out the difference between kill -- -27913and pkill -9 -P 27913

Comment: @norok2 I've updated python script I tested above, hope It helped

Comment: according to the `kill` manual, `kill -- -27913` sends signal `27913` to all known processes. I wouldn't be sure what would happen in this case, given that the `27913` signal is unknown. My best bet is that `pkill -9 -P 27913` just took a while to effectively kill the processes. Note that `pkill ... -P ...` will not kill the parent process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kill the process by its ID
for example:
use this command to list your python file  `ps -A| grep python`
and kill the process : `kill 27913`